# Cloud data fusion Http Property Json Field mapping in Macro

Tags: macros, google-cloud-data-fusion

How to specify Cloud data fusion's Http Property Json Field mapping in GCS Argument Setter's json config file? I want to use the json field mapping as a macro in HTTP Property node.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the the field Mapping required in the Http plugin properties is something like the following

[SampleFieldMappingForTwoStringTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM9Hv.png)

Then you can use the following sample entry in the argument setter json to define the Field Mapping macro(where fieldMapping is the name of the Macro in the Http plugin properties).

```
{
    "arguments" : [
        { "name" : "fieldMapping", "type" : "string", "value" : "/a:a,/b:b"}
    ]
}
```